# WebView is not working, when I set project to Target SDK Version 29 from SDK version 28

Tags: android

webview working fine in Target sdk version 28, When I upgrade to target sdk version 29. webview stops working in real devices. it's working fine in emulators. Help please

```
web_view_post_activity_content.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    web_view_post_activity_content.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    web_view_post_activity_content.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web_view_post_activity_content.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null && (url.startsWith("https://")  || url.startsWith("http://"))) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check here my repository which is working in API 29 as well https://github.com/shylendramadda/android-webview-java. Let me know if you face any issues

Comment: can you post your complete URL and manifest here. If your URL starts with `http` then you should add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in Manifest file under the application tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to load the HTML content in encoded format

```
String base64version = Base64.encodeToString(htmlData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
webView.loadData(base64version, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "base64");
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: IN my case I add your code. But HTML content-only view  . It is not rendering

Comment: Can you post a question along with the code that you have tried?